# Linear Transformation Orthogonality

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, orthonormal

> True or False:
>
> If $T$ is a linear transformation from $R^n$ to $R^n$
>
> such that
>
> $$T\left(\vec{e_1}\right), T\left(\vec{e_2}\right), \ldots,  T\left(\vec{e_n}\right)  $$
>
> are all unit vectors
>
> then $T$ must be an orthogonal transformation

The answer is ?
I know a linear transformation is orthogonal if it preserves the length of vectors.
And I understand a linear transformation is orthogonal if $$T\left(\vec{e_1}\right), T\left(\vec{e_2}\right), \ldots,  T\left(\vec{e_n}\right)  $$  form an orthonomal basis.

But how do I prove that withough knowing what the $T$, transformaton, does to the elementary column vectors...?
Could anybody help me prove this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

False.  Let $T$ be the linear transformation represented by the matrix whose first row is all 1's, and the other rows are all 0's.  $T(e_i)=e_1$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T e_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \sum_{i=1}^k e_i$. Then $T$ is invertible, and $\|T e_k \| = 1$ for all $k$.